# not able to convert canvas to image - server side

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, nginx

am not able to convert html5 canvas to image on server

my code  : **JavaScript**

```
var testCanvas = document.getElementById("viewport");

    var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {
            text1: canvasData
        },
        success: function(response) {

alert(response + '.png');
}
```

php code : **process.php**

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 6) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}


$rawData  = $_POST['text1'];
$filteredData = explode(',', $rawData);

$unencoded = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);
$dr = generateRandomString() ;

$fp = fopen('upload/' . $dr .'.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $unencoded);
fclose($fp); 

echo $dr;


?>
```

I don't get it what is wrong with my code , I have googled alot but did not find any  solution helpful 
and am using nginx on centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem then I discovered that I need to give write permission to the directory that I need to save the image in

you can do it by this command :

Navigate to folder and

`chmod -R 777` .  The `-R` makes it recursive.